# Disable surface auto rotate using a powershell script/command

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script where I disable windows auto rotate (for microsoft surface) and I can't find documentation on this topic.

Comment: What have you tried untill now?
Stack Overflow isn't a free Coding Service. If you got a problem with a specific problem in you code feel free to ask. I would advise you to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: why not try doing it via GPO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoRotation is controlled by a registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation\Enable` set to `0` to disable and `1` to enable:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation -Name Enable -Value 0 -Type DWord
```

Needs to be run as Admin user and will apply at next logon.

Comment: thank you! where do you find this kind of documentation?

Comment: This one came from my archive of solutions from old project requirements, likely found with google and/or trial error testing.